# Mongoose nested array update else add new one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to save new / update existing mongoose nested array? Do we need different function to achieve (save new/update existing) this or do we need separate function for each task?

```
Dummy Model 
var user = new Schema({
    name : String,
    cars: [{brand: String, prices:[ {color : String, value: String}] }],

}

let saveUpdate = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: req.id }, 
     { $set: { cars: ----   } }
 );
```

I have to save new car details and update car model or update price value based on  color field

Comment: I've answered similar question recently. Maybe you would like to take a look at it, on how to create a efficient document - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71013819/2822041

Comment: I have multiple nested , let me try with  your example